# Excel - Live filter of list based on another column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365, microsoft-excel-2019

In Excel, I'm looking to get a breakdown of the values in one column (IDs) by the values in another (status).

#### Input

```
| ID | Status   |
|----|----------|
|  1 | Complete |
|  2 | Active   |
|  3 | New      |
|  4 | New      |
|  5 | New      |
|  6 | Complete |
```

#### Desired Output

```
| Status   | IDs     |
|----------|---------|
| Complete | 1, 6    |
| Active   | 2       |
| New      | 3, 4, 5 |
```

#### Google Sheets Workaround

In google sheets, you can do this with `JOIN`, `FILTER`, and `UNIQUE` as follows:

**Generate Unique Statuses**

[image: Generate Unique Statuses]

**Filter and Join Results**

[image: Filter and Join Results]

#### Other Workarounds

I can't use a pivot table, because I want a full list of the individual values, not any aggregated metrics.

I'm not sure if this is possible with Advanced Filter Query per [Filter one column, using another column as criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46845022/1366033), but I haven't seemed to get it to work.

The original input can be formatted as a "table" in excel if there's a way query it using Power Query or some other tool, but I'd love to get a live list of the available filter values.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Excel solution is (almost) exactly the same. UNIQUE is identical. The difference is the join:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER($B$2:$B$7,$C$2:$C$7=$E2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - this was staring me right in the face.  I think these are new(ish) features brought to excel and searching had just turned up the filter view or table filters for most things

Answer (score 3):

It seems these same functions in Google Sheets are available in Microsoft Excel as well:

- [**`UNIQUE`**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e) (Office 365)
- [**`FILTER`**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) (Office 365)
- [**`TEXTJOIN`**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) (2019)

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(A$2:A$7,B$2:B$7=D2))
```

#### Get Unique Values

[image: Get Unique Values]

#### Filter Column By Another Column and Join Results

[image: Filter Column By Another Column and Join Results]